# JavaScript: else-if condition under for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble understanding the condition in the else if statement under the for loop in my code. I'd really appreciate it if you could help.

This is an array of objects containing student information, name, study track, achievements, points. I just need help understanding this condition: i === (students.length) -1

```
 var students = [ 
  { name: 'Dave', track: 'Front End Development', achievements: 158, points: 14730 },
  { name: 'Jody', track: 'iOS Development with Swift', achievements: 175, points: 16375 },
  { name: 'Jordan', track: 'PHP Development', achievements: 55, points: 2025 },
  { name: 'Jody', track: 'Learn WordPress', achievements: 40, points: 1950 },
  { name: 'Trish', track: 'Rails Development', achievements: 5, points: 350 }
];

var htmlMessage = '';
var student;
var search;
var notFound = [];

function print(message) {
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
  outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
}

function getStudentReport( student ) {
  var report = '<h2>Student: ' + student.name + '</h2>';
  report += '<p>Track: ' + student.track + '</p>';
  report += '<p>Points: ' + student.points + '</p>';
  report += '<p>Achievements: ' + student.achievements + '</p>';
  return report;
}

while (true) {
  search = prompt('Search student records:\ntype a name Ex: Jody\n(or type "quit" to end)');
  if (search === '') {
    alert('Please enter a name to initiate search.')
  } else if (search === null || search.toLowerCase() === 'quit') {

      print('<h2>Thanks for using our student record search services.</h2><p>These names were not found : ' + 
            notFound.join(', ') + '</p>');
      break;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    student = students[i];
    if (student.name.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()) {
      htmlMessage = getStudentReport(student);
      print(htmlMessage);
      break;
    } else if (i === (students.length) -1){
        print('<p>' + search + ' was not found.</p>');
        notFound.push(search);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there an `if`? Where is the for loop?

Comment: If you're just asking what is that else if doing, it appears to be keeping track of when you reach the end of the loop and considering the search failed, adding the failed search term to an array and breaking out of the loop

Comment: I just posted the rest of the code, sorry this is the first time i use stack overflow, and I'm still getting used to their formatting.

Comment: @KevinF you should  post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The else if is checking for the end of the loop and considering the search failed:

```
//if you are at the end of the array (searched through all students)
else if (i === (students.length) -1){
    //alert user that their search was not found
    print('<p>' + search + ' was not found.</p>');
    //push the failed search term into an array
    notFound.push(search);
    //break out of the loop, necessary because of the way the loop is 
    //written (while(true)) will go forever if not broken
    break;
}
```

...it is -1 because an arrays first item starts at 0 while the length starts counting at 1 ;-)
So there is a difference oft -1.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you so much, it makes perfect sense now!